# Excel services cannot open workbook

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint

I am trying to open a workbook (excel 2010) in sharepoint 2010 with Excel services on the server. No matter what workbook I try to open (even if I create one from scratch) the "OpenWorkbookForEditing" method of excel services fails with "The workbook that you selected cannot be opened. The workbook may be in an unsupported file format, or it may be corrupt."

I have googled the daylights out of this and all the answers on the web dont seem to fit. I have reset IIS, I have removed all secuirty settings in the trust centre of excel, I have tried .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm files, I have made sure the excel file is in a trusted location in SharePoint.

I am completely baffled by this.

```
        SPListItem newListItem = SPContext.Current.Web.GetListItem(SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[Constants.SharePointListName.TemporaryFileLibrary].RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + SPContext.Current.Web.Properties[SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName].ToString());

        Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelService cli = new Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelService();
        Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.Status[] status;


        // Open the workbook. - THIS IS THE POINT OF FAILURE.
        string sessionId = cli.OpenWorkbookForEditing(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/" + newListItem.File.Url, "", "", out status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the value of:

```
 SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/" + newListItem.File.Url
```

It may be that this is not an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Excel services "Service Application Associations" for the web appplication is configured.

You can enable the feature at

Application Management->Web Applications ->Manage web applications->Select your web application->Service Connections